# Checking whether a function is called when another function is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am new to AngularJS and Jasmine. Given the following controller, how do I test whether the `allPanelsRetrieved()` function is called when the `$scope.getPanels` is triggered?

```
angular.
module('panelList').
  controller('PanelListController', ['Panel', 'PanelSelection', '$scope', '$location', '$uibModal', '$rootScope',
    function PanelListController(PanelSelection, $scope, $location, $uibModal, $rootScope) {

      $scope.maxAbv = 2;
      $scope.minAbv = 12;
 

      this.allPanelsRetrieved = (index, before, filterParams) => {
        .....
      };

      $scope.getPanels = () => {
        const filterParams = {};
        filterParams.abv_lt = $scope.minAbv;
        filterParams.abv_gt = $scope.maxAbv;


        $scope.currentPagePanels = this.allPanelsRetrieved (1,[], filterParams);
      };

}]).
component('panelList', {
  templateUrl: '/components/panel-list/panel-list.template.html',
  controller:'PanelListController',
});
```

Comment: add `console.log('called')` to it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want allPanelsRetrived to be called, then simply use a boolean.

```
var bool = false

this.allPanelsRetrieved = (index, before, filterParams) => {
        .....
        bool=true;
      };

      $scope.getPanels = () => {
        if (bool) {
        const filterParams = {};
        filterParams.abv_lt = $scope.minAbv;
        filterParams.abv_gt = $scope.maxAbv;

        $scope.currentPagePanels = this.allPanelsRetrieved (1,[], filterParams);

        } else {
            // allPanelsRetrieved was not called
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that **allPanelsRetrieved** seems to be a private(local) method and used inside that controller.

1. You need not test private(local) methods execution.
2. If you still want to check if the method is triggered or not you can use jasmine's `toHaveBeenCalled()` method

   execept(myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
   passes when method is called.